# Angular 2. Doubled custom tags

Tags: angular, typescript, tags

I have some specific problem. I'm new in angular 2, so i think the solution is very simple.

So, I have custom tag which I have created previously. I add some components, directives and services in it. The name of my main component is "reddit". There situated form with two labels and inputs. 
When I add in my index.html one instance of reddit tag - everything is ok. 
But as soon as I double it, like this:

```
<reddit>Loading...</reddit>
<reddit>Loading</reddit>
```

ld be loaded and shown. The second one show only the "Loading" message. I think the problem in my config files. 
Can you look at it and help me? Thx!

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "the-basics-of-angular-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "go": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

my system.config.js

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

code of my custom component:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Link} from "../list/link";
import {ComponentList} from "../list/component-list.component";
import {LinkService} from "../service/link.service";
import {Logger} from "../service/logger.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'reddit',
    moduleId: module.id,
    styleUrls: ['reddit.css'],
    templateUrl: "component.html",
    providers: [LinkService, Logger]
})

export class RedditAppComponent{

    @ViewChild(ComponentList)
    private child : ComponentList;

    constructor(private linkService : LinkService){
    }
    title : string = "";
    link : string = "";
    linkList : Link[] = new Array<Link>();
    addArticle(title : string, link : string){
        this.linkService.addData(new Link(title, link));
        this.title = "";
        this.link = "";
        this.child.childMethod();
        return false;
    }
    deleteArticle(){
        this.linkService.deleteData();
        return false;
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.linkList = this.linkService.getData();
    }
}
```

And html schema of custom component:

```
<form class="ui large form segment" #form="ngForm">
    <h3 class="ui header">Add new row</h3>

    <div class="field">
        <label>Header:</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="title" name="title">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Link:</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="link" name="link">
    </div>

    <button class="ui positive right floated button" (click)="addArticle(title, link)">
        Send
    </button>
    <button class="ui positive right floated button" (click)="deleteArticle()">
        Delete
    </button>
</form>
<list-components [links] = "linkList"></list-components>
```

Comment: Loading the same root component more than once is currently not supported. AFAIR there is some hack to change the selector before loading the 2nd instance.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: you cant create multiple instance of one component directly however you can divide it into sub component see this plunker :https://next.plnkr.co/edit/pkPYfm?utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview